# Solrnet: How to use QueryelevationComponent in .net?

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am using SolrNet for site search. However, now I need to show some documents at the top for specific queries. I went through the Query Elevation manual  http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent and set up solrconfig.xml accordingly. The the debugging url mentioned in the manual is working pretty well.

I just don't know how to use  Query elevation component with Solrnet. I cannot find any code example in SolrNet wiki that shows how to use elevate.xml. Any example, suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the QueryElevatorComponent documentation on the wiki, you have a few options for enabling this for use with the SolrNet client.

1. You can add the following parameter to your SolrNet client query, to tell Solr to use the elevate [RequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRequestHandler) instead of the default.

   ```
   solr.Query("ipod", new QueryOptions {
        ExtraParams = new Dictionary<string, string> {
           {"qt", "elevate"}
        }
    });
   ```
2. Modify your default request handler in the solrconfig.xml file to add the elevate component as last-component. Below is a modified version of solrconfig.xml that comes with the Solr distribution sample file. **Note:** This assumes that you have the elevator searchcComponent defined as shown in the wiki page.

   ```
   <requestHandler name="search" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
      <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
      will be overridden by parameters in the request
       -->
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <int name="rows">10</int>
     </lst>

     ...

     <arr name="last-components">
       <str>elevator</str>
     </arr>
   </requestHandler>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you need to do client-side (i.e. in SolrNet) to activate this feature. It's configured and activated purely server-side.

Comment: ok. so what you are saying is if a query,q,  matches the elevator.xml setting, then i'll see the elevated results using the usual 'solr.Query(q)'  method?

Comment: Using the example given in the QueryElevationComponent, the following query doesn't retrieve any results:             http://localhost:8983/solr/core0//select?q=ipod  but the following query returns the elevated product: http://localhost:8983/solr/core0//elevate?q=ipod  Do you think that because the query 'ipod' doesn't have any documents associated with it, it could lead solr to ignore elevatore.xml as well? Also note the use of 'elevate' vs 'select' in the two urls.

Comment: @Raza: you didn't mention you were using a separate request handler. Either add the QueryElevationComponent to your standard request handler, or select a different request handler with `qt` as explained by Paige Cook.

Comment: But how to query in both handler parallely? It means from one web page, query should perform in Select handler and for another page query should perform in another handler. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @MauricioScheffer : I have already tried with qt parameter but with that it perform a query in select handler instead of another one.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer : I am facing same problem as asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390870/use-different-solr-requesthandlers-for-different-webpages). Can you please suggest?