# Use different solr requesthandlers for different webpages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, solr, nopcommerce, solrnet

I am using solrnet. I have two handler. 
1) /Default handler
2) /mysearch handler

1st one is used for few of webpages & 2nd one is used for other webpages.

So, how can I use both of handlers for different webpages?

Please advise me this is possible or not?

Comment: Can You Tell me How you call Handler from your application..?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/solrnet/ZA-bv9dkh_0/NZSSF0p-U1gJ